# Cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to '<anonymous type: System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid> TemplateReviewId>

Tags: c#, linq

As i have coded something like this.

```
var recordX = (from x in en.TemplateRevisions
                       where x.PracticeId == _PracticeId
                       group x by x.TemplateId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           TemplateReviewId = (from l in en.TemplateRevisions
                                               where l.TemplateId == g.Key.Value
                                               orderby l.DateChanged descending
                                               select l.TemplateReviewId
                                               ).Take(1)
                       }).ToList();
```

Here as i try to access it using like this.

```
var records = (from x in en.TemplateRevisions
                       where recordX.Contains(x.TemplateReviewId)

                       )
```

this throws error like here `record.Contains(x.TemplateReviewId)` need to access this anonymous list.

First code is correct as i have made but as i try to access using contains throws the **Cannot convert from `'System.Guid'` to `'<anonymous type: System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid> TemplateReviewId>`**

Here is the screenshot to which i found in debugger.

[Linq query using debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx0e3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement creates a list of objects of an anonymous type, for no obvious reason. Usually, if you find yourself with an anonymous type with a single property, it's better to just select the value instead, like this:

```cs
var recordX = (from x in en.TemplateRevisions
               where x.PracticeId == _PracticeId
               group x by x.TemplateId into g
               // Just select the guid directly
               select (from l in en.TemplateRevisions
                       where l.TemplateId == g.Key.Value
                       orderby l.DateChanged descending
                       // Note: select a single element as just a Guid,
                       // rather than a "limited to 1 element sequence"
                       select l.TemplateReviewId).FirstOrDefault())
               .ToList();
```

Then you'll have a `List<Guid>` - which will work better for your second query.

I suspect there's also a simpler way of representing the first query, but I haven't tried to address that as it's not really part of this question.

Comment: Its still showing List<IQueryable<Guid>> record as point it there.

Comment: @KapilGupta: What do you mean by "record as point it there"? Are you saying the type of `recordX` is `List<IQueryable<Guid>>`? It doesn't *look* like it should be... if you hover over the `Take(1)` call, what type does that show?

Comment: @KapilGupta: Note that if you could provide a [mcve] within the question, it would be easier for us to verify this for ourselves.

Comment: as i point to 'var recordX' then it shows List<IQueryable<Guid>> as i have hovered it there.

Comment: if i hover over take(1) call it still shows as "IQueryable<Guid> IQueryable<Guid>.Take<Guid>(int count)(+ 1 overload)"

Comment: How should i convert it into List<Guid>

Comment: @KapilGupta use `First()` instead of `Take(1)`

Comment: @Johnbot thank you as First() is not working i used FirstOrDefault() it worked like a charm.

Comment: Doh - I should really have worked out that `Take` still returned a sequence. Not enough coffee yet. Will update the answer.